# ImportError when using trackviz module

Tags: python

I'm assigned to run a python script, that imports several module

```
#filename: animate_vid_v6.py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import imageio
from trackviz import animate
import sys
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from operator import itemgetter
import colorsys
```

after I installed all the required modules, I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<some_directories>\animate_vid_v6.py", line 4, in <mo
dule>
    from trackviz import animate
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\trackviz\animate.py", line 9, in <module>
    from trackviz.tools import FigureAxes
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\trackviz\tools.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import Divider, LocatableAxes, Size
ImportError: cannot import name 'LocatableAxes' from 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1' (
C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\__init__.py)
```

After I scrutinize that message, it is turn out that the `LocatableAxes` is no longer exists in scripts inside the `C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1` directory.

As you can see here, at the `C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\__init__.py`, there are no `LocatableAxes` module.

```
from . import axes_size as Size
from .axes_divider import Divider, SubplotDivider, make_axes_locatable
from .axes_grid import Grid, ImageGrid, AxesGrid

from .parasite_axes import host_subplot, host_axes
```

Does anybody has an idea /suggestions to fix this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `LocatableAxes` classes [have been deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.0.0.html#deprecation-of-locatableaxes-in-toolkits) in Matplotlib 3.0.0, but it seems trackviz hasn't been updated since then to avoid using these classes. Indeed, the [trackviz GitHub repository](https://github.com/marximus/trackviz) hasn't been updated for about three years.

If you really want to use trackviz you will have to install an older version of Matplotlib.